# Why universal enveloping algebra U$(\mathfrak{g})$ has the same representation theory as that of $\mathfrak{g}$?

Tags: lie-algebras, universal-algebra, representation-of-algebras

I am new to concepts from Lie algebra theory, so I was reading [Lectures on Lie groups ad Lie algebras](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lectures-on-lie-groups-and-lie-algebras/130B9AC92F0D31618699955D2A567786) by Carter, Macdonald and Segal.

At the third chapter we are introducing universal enveloping algebra of any Lie algebra, there it is claimed $U(\mathfrak{g})$ has the same representation theory as $\mathfrak{g}$ :

[image]

but I couldn't understand what does it mean they have "same" representation theory.

I think what he explained is that any representation $\rho$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ induces a representation of $\rho'$ of $U(\mathfrak{g}$)  and vice versa, but I am not sure if it is meant that map $\rho \rightarrow \rho'$ is bijective?

The reason for asking about bijectivity is similar to: for every odd integer, there is a even integer (say by ading $1$), and also for every even integer there is a odd integer (say also by adding $1$). But one probably wants to hear we subtract $1$ from even integers to make the map bijective.

Comment: so do you mean that since $g \subset U(g)$ , multiplication of $U(g)$ on $V$ restricts to that of $g$ on $V$ and also can be expanded from $g$ to $U(g)$?

Comment: See also the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686452/the-category-of-lie-algebra-representations).

Comment: Ok, I think the word 'natural way' hints for what I asked in comment.